# Page attribute not found wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress, I developed my **custom template**, page attribute is work. I can choose different template from page attribute and I used many different templates.

In the screen option, I have checked page attribute but It is not coming out. When I change to other theme, it appears. But when I change back to my theme, it is not coming.

What might be the issue here ?

Comment: My guess would be your custom theme doesn't have any additional page templates to choose from.

Comment: Try to check style.css in your theme folder..it might be happen because of missing style.css in template directory.

Comment: Question formatted and corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page templates are limited to your theme. It is upto the theme developers to setup the template or not.

If you need to create a custom template, you can do that by creating a file `page-{template-name}.php` and WordPress automatically shows that in your `Page Template` dropdown.

Comment: I have tried that way, I already chose the custom template to my page last few month, it is still work for now. But for the new other template, I can't choose because I can't find the page attribute box. I try from screen option and i checked but not come out. When i change the whole template, twenty eleven, page attribute work. But not work in my template